# Javascript function in head not recognized in body

Tags: javascript

Why does this code not work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <title>Euroqpa</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="type=text/javascript">
   <!--
    function drawcanvas() {
     var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
     ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
     ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
    }
   //-->
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
  drawcanvas();
 //-->
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I think that the function defined in the head should be recognized by the script in the body. Isn't it?

It says: Uncaught ReferenceError: drawcanvas is not defined

Comment: You've commented it out???

Comment: Check the jsfiddle i made, it works
http://jsfiddle.net/r3nU9/

Comment: @KyleMuir: Nope, that's perfectly normal (if a bit old-fashioned) in `script` tags.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wow, crazy. I've never seen that before.

Comment: Also `<!-- -->` is unnecessary nowadays, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first sight your `type` attribute on the head script is wrong

Replace

```
<script type="type=text/javascript">
```

by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Or better yet, don't specify it at all, as JavaScript is (and always has been) the default `type`.

Comment: Also, `<!-- -->` is unnecessary nowadays, IMO.

Comment: My fault. It was this :(

Answer (score 3):

Browsers ignore `script` elements with an unrecognised `type` attribute (this is *exploited* by inline templating).

Simply drop the `type` attribute all together, it's not required.

Answer (score -1):

It might be because you have `<!--` before and `-->` after the function.

These are comments for HTML not javascript and will cause an error

Comment: See TJ Crowder comment above (below OP). (*That man knows what he's about.*)

Comment: That used to actually be good practice, in order to keep script code from spilling into the page for browsers that didn't understand `<script>`.  Nowadays it's probably not useful.